# jboss-as-maven-plugin deploy error - JBAS012144 connection timed out

Tags: maven

I am trying to deploy a simple war to Jboss 6.2 but running into this error:

java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:8080. The connection timed out

In my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.Final</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <port>8080</port>
                <jbossHome>D:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.2</jbossHome>
                <fileName>target/xxx.war</fileName>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Thanks to James Perkins
The port number must be the admin (default)